# primary key type for AWS RDS mysql aurora

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have a specific question on AWS RDS aurora recommendations. Which primary key type the best is for my usecase.

At first I will describe my current situation and after that what my current research results are:

I have a database currently running on an aws rds aurora 2 cluster (mysql 5.7). On that Multi Az Cluster i have a database with multiple tables. Some of these tables are quite large with more than 500Mio rows. On top of this Database runs a spring boot application with multiple instances to read and write data to these tables. At the moment we use UUID's as primary keys. So that primary key handling is easy with the multiple instances and Green-Blue Deployments and so on.
We store them as mentioned in mysql [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/storing-uuid-values-in-mysql-tables/#:%7E:text=BINARY(16)%20is%E2%80%A6%20well%E2%80%A6%20just%20binary!%20No%20character%20set%2C%20no%20collation%2C%20just%20sixteen%20bytes.%20Perfect%20for%20our%20need.) as binary(16) column.

A few days ago I saw a tweet from Vlad Mihalcea referring to this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/uuid-database-primary-key/#:%7E:text=Because%20the%20B%2BTree%20index%20needs%20to%20rebalance%20itself%20in%20order%20to%20maintain%20its%20equidistant%20tree%20structure%2C%20the%20random%20key%20values%20will%20cause%20more%20index%20page%20splits%20and%20merges%20as%20there%20is%20no%20pre%2Ddetermined%20order%20of%20filling%20the%20tree%20structure.). Vlad said the following:

> Because the B+Tree index needs to rebalance itself in order to maintain its equidistant tree structure, the random key values will cause more index page splits and merges as there is no pre-determined order of filling the tree structure.

And than he mentioned that this fact is even worse for mysql, because the entire table is basically a clustered index. This was a little bit of an alert for me. It raises some questions in my head:

- I know that AWS just use the mysql 5.7 dialect for the aurora 2. They reworked the internals of the database as far as I know. So I wonder if a UUID is such a bad idea? If aurora 2 stores the data like mysql. Is there a difference to aurora 3?
- Vlad mentioned TSID as alternative. Are there any experience with this datatype on aws aurora mysql clusters?

Did anyone have some experiances on that topic. I try to use the [best practices side](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.BestPractices.html) from the aws documentation. But there were no useful hints for my topic. Maybe I missed something. I'm thankful for any thoughts.

Comment: Interesting related discussions on ULID and UUIDv7 [here](https://blog.daveallie.com/ulid-primary-keys), storing ULIDs as primary keys [here](https://github.com/ulid/spec/issues/25) and UUID or GUID as Primary Keys? Be Careful! [here](https://tomharrisonjr.com/uuid-or-guid-as-primary-keys-be-careful-7b2aa3dcb439#52ca)

Comment: These are interesting articles. The some of my questions i not explicitly wrote but comes with this topic. Thank you for the recommendations!